# I dont see the commands window in eclipse - Java Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Im using eclipse (Win7 if its matter) and when I write something I never see the commands window.
For example,
When I type: " android: " it should to open me a window with possible commands such as "text, "textSize", and its not show nothing.

What should I do to fix it?
Thanks in advance.

The code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.firstproject.StartingPoint" >


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text
          />


</RelativeLayout>
```

The text "android:text" its where I tried to open the commands window, without sucess...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Java Proposals may have been turned off for some reason. In Eclipse, find the following in the menus:

1. Window
2. Preferences
3. Java
4. Editor
5. Content Assist
6. Advanced

Then check the boxes labelled `Java Proposals` and hit Apply.

You can see the official Eclipse documentation for `Content Assist` here:
http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Feditor%2Fref-preferences-content-assist.htm

**EDIT: Summarizing the comments below**

Failing this, some other things you can try:

- Clean the project (`project -> clean`) and restart eclipse
- Test to see if it is only happening in that one class. If so, you can try creating the class again

Comment: Is  it happening for just 1 class? Or in every class?

Comment: To be honest I am just trying to code my first application. Im just start coding with eclipse today so I dont try so many classes

Comment: I am watching in a video guide for Android Application and I see that he has this command window while I dont have it

Comment: Ok, I see... To confirm, you are holding down Ctrl+spacebar to get the list of coding suggestions?

Comment: Yes, I am. For example, Im trying to do that in a <TextView> and then in the left side at the bottom its write: "Element <textview> is unkown".

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project (`project -> clean`) and restarting eclipse?

Comment: I did it now...  same

Comment: Ok, do you mind updating your question with the code you're having a problem with? You may have a typo somewhere

Comment: I Updated my message.

Comment: Thanks. I notice you haven't given your TextView an ID. You could try putting in `android:id="@+id/text"` below your `android:text` line. If the `android:text` line is now fine, and the new `id` line is red, this will confirm if there's a problem with the IDE

Comment: I dont know how, but somehow its started to work for me before a couple of minutes. Probably one of the things that you told me to do worked.

Comment: Eclipse can be strange at times where any one of 1000 things can fix it... glad to hear you got it working. Good luck with your android development!

Comment: Thank you so much again :)